# How do I change the color of a hyperlink in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink

I put a link to a website in a powerpoint presentation.

The link comes out red on the screen.

That color looks bad against the brown background.

I would like it to be white or yellow or bright orange; or something that would be better for reading.

The `Format` menu doesn't have a place to change the font color or size.

When I use the `Home` menu, and I try to change the font (with or without hi-lighting) the change does not happen.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the design tab. Click on colors (drop down menu to the right). Select a color scheme or better yet click on create new theme colors at them bottom of the drop down menu. There, you can change the color of the hyperlink before and after it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to change it via theme colors, detailed instructions on Microsoft site: [2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/change-the-color-of-a-hyperlink-HP001162076.aspx), [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/powerpoint-help/change-the-color-of-hyperlink-text-HA010232208.aspx), [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/powerpoint-help/change-the-color-of-hyperlink-text-HA010338279.aspx).

Comment: Just found this also discussed in another question.  I can change the size and the font, but I am stuck with one color throughout the entire document; I think.  I'm learning this as I go.

Comment: @User.1 Well, you can use several themes in the same presentation. Create separate files, have different color themes, and then paste slides into one file with "Keep source formatting".

Comment: Linking to answers isn't useful if the link goes down or the page is deleted. Perhaps you could transfer the instructions into your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the hyperlink (right-click it and select Remove Hyperlink). That converts it into plain text and you can then format it any way you like, including the underline.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I think I found the trick; I get one color of hyperlink font per powerpoint file.  From there I can change the font and size, but not the color.  I'll live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to apply the link to the shape that holds the text rather than to the text itself.  That way the text formatting doesn't change (or rather you can change to whatever YOU want it to be).

The only drawback for most users is that the link doesn't change to the "Visited link" color after it's been clicked.

Answer (score -1):

First, to change the color of hyperlinked text in PowerPoint, start with the following:

Go to the Design tab

Click on the arrow down in Colors

Click on Create New Theme Colors at the bottom of the drop down bar

In the menu that pops up, click the arrow next to Hyperlink- choose the desired color of the link.

Under this you will see Followed Hyperlink-select the same color as the above to maintain the previous color (shown below).

Next to Hyperlink, click the arrow and choose whatever color you prefer for your presentation.

Choose the same color for the Followed Hyperlink if you want the color to remain the same after it is clicked on (and to avoid the usual maroon “used hyperlink” look).

Source:
https://www.brainshark.com/ideas-blog/2012/August/change-hyperlink-colors-in-powerpoint